# Is it possible to reverse a tag synonym after the merge is complete?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

On Cooking, we just [noticed](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/what-makes-a-burger-a-tagburger) that using the word "hamburgers" for a tag may feel forced in cases where "burger" would sound good. However, eight years ago somebody [created a tag synonym](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/tags-needing-synonymification-consolidation) in the other direction. Now it is impossible to use a tag [burger](/questions/tagged/burger), only [hamburgers](/questions/tagged/hamburgers). Apparently, they didn't notice the possible edge cases back then.

Is it possible now, after the fact, to somehow have the tag become [burger](/questions/tagged/burger) and [hamburgers](/questions/tagged/hamburgers) be the synonym? In general, is there such functionality available to moderators or high rep users? If not, can it be fixed manually if we ask for it?

Answer (score 9):

Moderators (♦) have access to a utility to manage Tag Synonyms.

On a browser, that utility has all synonyms listed and a **swap** button to "swap synonym with master".

It appears when moderators mouse over that row in the list.

[image]

If you ask on your Meta, and the proposed swap appears to have consensus, then what you wish to do can be done easily by a moderator of your site.

Comment: Interesting, never knew about the swap feature and I was exploring that page on my iPhone, where it (of course) never appeared ...

Answer (score 3):

As a ♦ moderator, you can outright delete tag synonyms on the list page (/tags/synonyms), in your case https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms; it has a search function, and then synonymize the tags in the other direction.

High rep users can only approve (new) synonyms, not delete or swap them, not even when working together; also, in general, on most sites tag synonyms are hardly looked upon.